# What would be the output of this script?

Tags: php

In the following script

```
<?php
$people = array("Joe", "Pete", "Mike", "Mark");
print_r (each($people));
?>
```

if the 3rd line was reiterated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input:

```
$people = array("Joe", "Pete", "Mike", "Mark");

print_r(each($people));
print_r(each($people));
print_r(each($people));
print_r(each($people));
var_dump(each($people));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Joe
    [value] => Joe
    [0] => 0
    [key] => 0
)
Array
(
    [1] => Pete
    [value] => Pete
    [0] => 1
    [key] => 1
)
Array
(
    [1] => Mike
    [value] => Mike
    [0] => 2
    [key] => 2
)
Array
(
    [1] => Mark
    [value] => Mark
    [0] => 3
    [key] => 3
)
bool(false)
```